# Alternative Content for FB Like Box for non-logged in users

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have a facebook Like box on my website for an age-restricted page. The problem is that it just appears blank - no sort of explanation to the user why nothing is showing.

Is there any way to provide an alternate content in the like box space, that tells the user that they need to log-in to Facebook in order to show the box?

Comment: Since your problem was solved, please accept an answer as best answer to close the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for a somewhat rough and ready approach, but it does the job: as Robbert pointed out, the default version doesn't have a specified height. So by putting it inside a container with a defined height and overflow set to hidden, I can place the alternative content underneath - that way if the like box shows, it bumps the alternative content out of the way.

```
<div style="height:65px;overflow:hidden;">
<div 
    class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://mysite.etc"
    data-send="false" 
    data-height="20" 
    data-width="300"  
    data-show-faces="true" 
    >
    </div>
<p>Alternative content goes here.</p>   
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution as well. You did a good job building on the ideas I gave without having to bother with JavaScript or Facebook's SDKs.